# MSBuild and Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution that contains an ASP.NET Web Site (file-based) project. I'm currently using the following command in my build script to build the entire solution:

```
<pathtomsbuild.exe> 
     /t:rebuild /nologo 
     /p:OutputPath=..\some_dynamic_dir 
     /p:NoWarn=1685 <solutionfilename>
```

However, web site projects do not come with a .csproj file, and the location to which they are compiled / published is controlled within the .sln file using the property:

```
<configuration>.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath
```

Since I'm creating a dynamic output directory via my build script (so that it includes version info), I have a real problem with the fact that the default publish location for web site projects is:

```
<solutiondir>\PrecompiledWeb\<NameOfProject>
```

I would prefer to specify this location when I call MSBuild, but I don't see how. Any thoughts? Do I really need to resort to manually calling aspnet_compiler with my desired output path, or is there some property I can pass to msbuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following parameters works fine for me:

```
/t:Rebuild;ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication 
/p:OutDir=..\some_dynamic_dir\bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=..\some_dynamic_dir\
```

Comment: This is not working for me,this is the only thing that need's to be modified?

Comment: Once you specify the OutDir, MsBuild injects _PublishedWebsites into the path, so I'm not sure this answer is correct in that we still aren't able to specify the precise output path, right?